# Pyspark Count includes Nulls

Tags: pyspark

Running a simple example -

```
dept = [("Finance",10),("Marketing",None),("Sales",30),("IT",40)]
deptColumns = ["dept_name","dept_id"]
rdd = sc.parallelize(dept)
df = rdd.toDF(deptColumns)
df.show(truncate=False)

print('count the dept_id, should be 3')
print('count: ' + str(df.select(F.col("dept_id")).count()))
```

We get the following output -

```
+---------+-------+
|dept_name|dept_id|
+---------+-------+
|Finance  |10     |
|Marketing|null   |
|Sales    |30     |
|IT       |40     |
+---------+-------+

count the dept_id, should be 3
count: 4
```

I'm running on databricks and this is my stack -
Spark 3.0.1 scala 2.12, DBR 7.3 LTS

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle difference between the `count` function of the Dataframe API and the `count` function of Spark SQL. The first one simply counts the rows while the second one can ignore `null` values.

You are using [Dataframe.count()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.count.html). According to the documentation, this function

> returns the number of rows in this DataFrame

So the result `4` is correct as there are 4 rows in the dataframe.

If `null` values should be ignored, you can use the [Spark SQL function count](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#count) which can ignore `null` values:

> count(expr[, expr...]) - Returns the number of rows for which the supplied expression(s) are all non-null.

For example

```python
df.selectExpr("count(dept_id)").show()
```

returns `3`.

Comment: I've used this - which apparantly includes non-null as well:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.count.html?highlight=count#pyspark.sql.functions.count

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative solution to @werner is using the
[pyspark.sql.functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.count.html?highlight=count#pyspark.sql.functions.count)

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

print('count: ' + str(df.select(F.count(F.col("dept_id"))).collect()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not complete. Maybe you can just add 'isNotNull()' before count()

My code like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count

print('count the dept_id, should be 3')
print('count: ' + str(df.filter(col("dept_id").isNotNull()).count()))
```

Comment: The code should count 3 entries (discarding the null one), it counts to 4.
also tried this and it still counts to 4

```
print('count in spark')
print(df.select(
  F.when(F.col('dept_id').isNull(), True).otherwise(None)
).count())
```

Comment: I don't want to use filter because it works on the df itself, and i'm going to use this in aggregate function on a single column and there's no filter on a column